# tomcat jar java working only with 8080

Tags: java, tomcat, nginx, tomcat7

I installed `nginx` and `tomcat in centos`, 
I recently purchased a script which contain jar java file.

If I upload it in `tomcat/webapps/myapp` the script works as expected if I open `mydomain.com:8080/myapp.`

If I upload it to `nginx/html/myapp` script not working as expected on `mydomain.com/myapp`.

I want to get correct output if load `mydomain.com/myapp`. Please anyone help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

So you're uploading the JAR to nginx? This won't work as it'll need Tomcat to run if I'm understanding what you're trying to do.

Configure nginx to proxy the request to Tomcat to get the Java app working - here has some good notes https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/javaservers/